# Windows 7 laptop: I don't want it to sleep or hibernate or logout

Tags: windows-7, windows, sleep

I've recently purchased a Windows 7 laptop. While I am a technical user, I am really not familiar with Windows.

Since I do run a lot of long (8-12 h) processes (scientific experiments) I want the laptop to not sleep and not hibernate, not log out when plugged in to the wall. I think this is fairly straight-forward stuff, and that I'm doing something wrong.

I've changed the power plan and configured it to only dim the display after 30 minutes ( I put never on when to put the computer to sleep). I played with the advanced options to no avail.

Power plan settings:

- Dim the display: on battery: 2 minutes, plugged in 30 minutes
- Turn off the display: on battery: 5 minutes, plugged in Never
- Put the computer to sleep: on battery 15 minutes, plugged in Never
- Adjust brightness: on battery ~80%, plugged in 100%

Advanced:

- Require password on wake up: yes / yes
- Turn off hard disk after: 10 minutes / 20 minutes
- Sleep/Sleep after 15 minutes / Never
- Sleep/Allow hybrid sleep: Off / Off
- Sleep/Hibernate after: 300 minutes / 300 minutes

So now I'm thinking it is the BS power plans from ASUS (the brand of the laptop) maybe they are configured incorrectly?

What I really want is that when plugged in it never sleeps or logs out or stops running in any Windows shape way or form.

Comment: Please edit you question and add your exact power plan settings (including the advanced tree if possible).

Comment: @techie007 I've edited the question a little bit to include the power plan settings.

Comment: Is the problem happening when the laptop's lid is closed, by any chance?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: it hasn't happened with the lid close, I haven't tried with the lid closed.

Comment: @carlosdc reset all settings to never sleep/never turn off

Comment: How long is it lasting until it goes to sleep?  "Sleep/Hibernate after: 300 minutes / 300 minutes" is 5 hours.  What happens when you also set this to "Never"?

Comment: @techie007 overnight. The times it has bothered me the most it has been running an experiment at 100% cpu and it just goes to sleep. That Sleep/Hibernate option does not have never as an option. It goes up to 100000 minutes. I'm going to try that overnight.

Comment: @techie007 would you mind writing your suggestion as an answer so I can accept it?